# MS Graph API: filter messages by subject length

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Is there a way to filter (or search) for outlook email messages where the subject length is less than (say) 20 characters using the Microsoft Graph API?

I've tried with a filter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=strlen(subject) le 20
```

but the `strlen` function is not recognised (also tried `subject.length` and `subject.size` but those are not recognised either).

No luck with search either:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="strlen(subject) le 20"
```

which just returns no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odata supports this using length http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_length eg

```
$filter=length(Subject) eq 19
```

But Microsoft haven't implemented this in the Graph the only valid operators are listed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http so startsWith,endswidth and contains

In any of the Exchange API's there doesn't exist a restriction to allow you to do that at the server level. The closest is in KQL the near operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference which you can do some pretty dynamic things with when matching around a subject. Otherwise the only option would be to enumerate and filter once you get the result.

Comment: Thanks [@Glen Scales](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080923/glen-scales). I couldn't see how KQL `near` would help find the subject length? Looks like I'll have to filter client side.

Comment: It more why do you need to find email with a subject length of 20 character, near can be used to find email with subject patterns eg particular words near each other etc as an alternative